# Conceptual questions about OOP and parent/child relationships

Tags: oop, parent-child

I'm designing on board game style mobile RPG and have a question about how to structure the objects.  Since this is conceptual, choose to answer in whatever language you want, though I mainly program in Javascript/JQuery/PHP.

Presuming the following:

```
- The mobile application has a Game() class
- The Game() has one Player() and one Dungeon()
- The Dungeon() has many DungeonRooms()
- A DungeonRoom() has many DungeonCards()
- A DungeonCard() has many DungeonCardActions() *1
- A DungeonCardAction() has an onClick() event
- An onClick() event can be designed to harm the Player()'s health. // e.g. "Put hand in Fire"
```

[1] Note: When you tap a card, card-specific actions are revealed

My question is, what is the rational way to harm the player's health?  I'm sure it's not:

```
function onClick()
{
    parent.parent.parent.parent.player.health -= 10;
}
```

That assumes that there is a strict object hierarchy and the sequence of depths never changed.

Is it that the Game() object is always passed into the constructor of every new object by reference, so whatever object has full access to browse the entire universe of other objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no better but only commonly preferred ways to do that for the sake of code readability and conceptual meanings of your objects.

Giving a first look, I notice that you use a single object for your player. A player is the person who control the player actor. An actor is controlled via its controller. Any other game actor can also be controlled by other types of controllers as well. Such approach liberates game content from game mechanics so that the programmer could focus on each individually.

Applying a little modification, I proposed a new model using the rules above. (there can always be another pretty solution)

- App has Game class.
- Game has Players and Content
- Content has Dungeons (game levels)
- Each dungeon has DungeonRooms that contains things below
- ==DungeonCard is an Actor.
- ==Your player unit is an Actor.
- Actors in the same room are aware of each other via their parents
- Each actor can be associated with controllers (mutually)
- Your player unit Actor is controlled by keyboard, mouse
- Your DungeonCard is controlled by your mouse
- DungeonCardAction is a controller method.
- Player moves are controller methods.

Edit: Assuming you are using a language that supports global/static/singleton objects, your Game class should only be allocated once during your application life time and can be exposed the whole game code via global scope, hence less constructor parameters.

Comment: Your comment about having the game as a global singleton makes sense, and was probably the piece I was looking for!  In this particular game the player is not a traditional "unit" in the room; it is a first person dungeon crawl closer to a game like Mist or a Hidden Object game.  So the player exists, but he exists as more of a global object.  Thanks for the advice!